# Observable 'save' should return EMPTY or a dummy value

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I see a common pattern in my application where functions return Observables that do not need to provide a `next()` value (i.e. `save()`) but may be part of an Observable chain.

In this working example (link below), I have a demo `BookService` with `save()` and `getBooks()`. The code example save 2 books, get books from service and console.log the books via a single observable chain.

I have tried these two options:

Option 1:

- `save(title: string): Observable<never>` returns `EMPTY`. This means subscriber's `next()` will never be called. To let the observable chain continue with a single value, I `pipe(defaultIfEmpty(true))` after calling `save()`.
- Pro: Function works and just call `complete()`. `save()` does not need to return a value with no meaning.
- Con: Calling `defaultIfEmpty(true)` to chain observable does not look intuitive.

Option 2:

- `save(title: string): Observable<boolean>` returns a value `of(true)`. Function works, where both `next()` and `complete()` will be called once.
- Pro: No need `defaultIfEmpty(true)` to chain observable.
- Con: `next()` is always called. Is this considered a con?

Option 3:

- Please let me know if there's a better way.

The [code example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-return-empty-or-value) provides both option 1 and option 2 (commented).

**Question:** What should functions like `save()` return? Are there written documentation/article on observables design for such scenario?

Appreciate your thoughts on this.

Comment: This is just your specific use case so there probably won't be any official guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that it depends on your usecase. Using Observables allows you to implement cancellation behaviour for your `.Save()` function. If it returns a value or just completes is up to you. Depending on your usage (are you always piping `defaultIfEmpty` onto it?) you can either go for the pure version (no value, just complete) or let it default to a value to make it easier on yourself.

What *is important* is that you document the behaviour the consumers of your `.Save()` function can expect of your observable. Will it indeed emit only a `true` value and complete? Or never emit a value?